# Is it possible to export a facebook page content?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, export

I need to export all of a facebook page content, including images, profile images, posts and comments.
Is there a way to do this? 
Or, do FB pages have a RSS?
thank you!
alessandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of work, but here's where you should start looking: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

There's no quick and easy way, since different pages display different content depending on who's looking at them. The API should be pretty straight forward. Big differences between working with the Graph API and an RSS feed would be:

1. Authentification
2. JSON format instead of xml.
3. More complex format. You have multiple nodes that connect to other nodes. You need to connect the dots :)